# Linear independence of two monomials

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f_1$ and $f_2$ be the monomials $f_1(x) = x$, $f_2(x) = x^2$. Are they linearly independent if viewed as functions on the two element sets $X=\{0,1\}$ and $X=\{1,2\}$?
We have $0x+1x^2=x^2$ and $1x+2x^2=x+2x^2$ or am I on the wrong track? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equations you wrote do not say whether they are independent or not.

Note that $x=x^{2}$ on $\{0,1\}$. So $f_1=f_2$ and we have linear dependence on this set. However $af_1+bf_2=0$ on $\{1,2\}$ implies $a+b=0$ and $a+4b=0$. Can you show that $a=b=0$ (which makes the functions linearly independent)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by $X=\{0,1\}$ and $X=\{1,2\}$. You are probably referring to the coefficients. Normally, one refers to the vector space of polynomials over a field. In that your polynomials are independent in (but do not form a basis of) the vector space of polynomials of order at most 2. That is, any polynomial of the form $ax^2+bx$ can be expressed in exactly one way as $cf_{2}(x)+df_{1}(x)$, namely with $a=c$ and $b=d$.

If you're asking whether the polynomials $x^2$ and $x+2x^2$ are independent then the answer is also yes.